# Прикрепление нескольких файлов к письму php

Tags: php

Как сделать атач нескольких файлов в письме?

```
  $filename = "image.png"; //Имя файла для прикрепления
  $filename1 = "111.jpg"; //Имя файла для прикрепления
  $to = "test@test.ru"; //Кому
  $from = "def@gmail.com"; //От кого
  $subject = "Test"; //Тема
  $message = "Текстовое сообщение"; //Текст письма
  $boundary = "---"; //Разделитель
  /* Заголовки */
  $headers = "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"";
  $body = "--$boundary\n";
  /* Присоединяем текстовое сообщение */
  $body .= "Content-type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n";
  $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printablenn";
  //$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n\n";
  $body .= $message."\n";
  $body .= "--$boundary\n";

  //foreach($attach as $filename){

  $file = fopen($filename, "r"); //Открываем файл
  $text = fread($file, filesize($filename)); //Считываем весь файл
  fclose($file); //Закрываем файл
  /* Добавляем тип содержимого, кодируем текст файла и добавляем в тело письма */
  $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n"; 
  $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
  $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n\n"; 
  $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($text))."\n";
  /////////////////////Добавление 2 файла//////////////////////////////////////////
  $file1 = fopen($filename1, "r"); //Открываем файл
  $text1 = fread($file1, filesize($filename1)); //Считываем весь файл
  fclose($file1); //Закрываем файл
  $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename1)."?=\n"; 
  $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
  $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename1)."?=\n\n"; 
  $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($text1))."\n";

//}

  $body .= "--".$boundary ."--\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); //Отправляем письмо
```

На почту приходит 1 фаил image.png
В чем причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вопросе отправке почтовых сообщений есть множество нюансов. Советую использовать готовое решение для отправки почты через php и не изобретать велосипед. Их готовых решений могу посоветовать [PhpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Довольно функциональная библиотека.

Пример в Вашими данными:

```
$files = [
    [
        'name'=>'image.png',
        'path'=>'/image.png'
    ],
    [
        'name'=>'111.jpg',
        'path'=>'/111.jpg'
    ]
];

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('def@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('test@test.ru');

$mail->Subject = 'Test';
$mail->Body = 'Текстовое сообщение';

foreach($files as $file){
    $mail->addAttachment($file['path'], $file['name']);
}

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```